# Не правильно работает триггер ORACLE BD

Tags: sql, база-данных, oracle, триггер

Делаю триггеры для базы данных с таблицей "Товары"(айди,имя,айди группы, входная цена, розничная цена, количество) и "Группы товаров" (айди, имя, количество, сводная стоимость, наценка).

У меня триггер обновления количества товаров в группе выдает null значение для  поля count в таблице групп для следующих запросов:

```
INSERT INTO product_group (name,markup) VALUES ('Телевизоры',0.2)

INSERT INTO PRODUCT (NAME, GROUP_ID,ENTRY_PRICE, COUNT)
VALUES ('Телевизор Philips',1, 10000, 5);
```

Таблица товаров:

1   Телевизор Philips   1   10000   12000   5

Таблица товаров:

1   Телевизоры  (null)  0   0,2

Триггер, с которым проблемы:

```
 create or replace NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER update_group_count
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON product
    FOR EACH ROW
    DECLARE
      v_group_id NUMBER;
      v_new_count NUMBER;
    BEGIN
      -- Получаем идентификатор группы товаров для текущего товара
      v_group_id := :NEW.group_id;
    
      -- Получаем новое значение "COUNT" для товара
      v_new_count := :NEW.count;
    
      -- Обновляем "COUNT" в группе товаров внутри блока транзакции
      UPDATE product_group
      SET count = (SELECT SUM(count) FROM product WHERE group_id = v_group_id)
      WHERE id = v_group_id;
    END;
```

При смены BEFORE на AFTER возникает данная ошибка:

```
Error starting at line : 1 in command -
INSERT INTO PRODUCT (NAME, GROUP_ID,ENTRY_PRICE, COUNT)
VALUES ('Телевизор Samsung',1, 10000, 5)
Error at Command Line : 1 Column : 9
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-04091: таблица USER1.PRODUCT изменяется, триггер/функция может не заметить это
ORA-06512: на  "USER1.UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT", line 4
ORA-04088: ошибка во время выполнения триггера 'USER1.UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT'
04091. 00000 -  "table %s.%s is mutating, trigger/function may not see it"
*Cause:    A trigger (or a user defined plsql function that is referenced in
           this statement) attempted to look at (or modify) a table that was
           in the middle of being modified by the statement which fired it.
*Action:   Rewrite the trigger (or function) so it does not read that table.
```

Полный код таблиц и триггеров:

```
CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT_GROUP"  

   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT "USER1"."GROUP_SEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL" NOT NULL ENABLE,  

    "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,  

    "COUNT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0,  

    "C_RETAIL" NUMBER DEFAULT 0,  

    "MARKUP" NUMBER DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE,  

     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_GROUP_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") 

  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS  

  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 

  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 

  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 

  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE,  

     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_GROUP_CHK1" CHECK (markup >= 0 AND markup <= 1 

) ENABLE 

   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE  

  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255  

 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 

  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 

  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 

  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 

  TABLESPACE "USERS" ; 

 

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICES"  

AFTER UPDATE OF MARKUP ON product_group 

FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

  -- Обновляем розничные цены в таблице "Товары" для соответствующей группы 

  UPDATE product 

  SET retail_price = entry_price * (1 + :NEW.markup) 

  WHERE group_id = :NEW.id; 

   -- Выполняем коммит изменений 

  COMMIT; 

EXCEPTION 

  WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    NULL; 

END; 

/ 

ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICES" ENABLE; 

 

 

  CREATE TABLE "USER1"."PRODUCT"  

   (    "ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT "USER1"."PRODUCT_SEQUENCE"."NEXTVAL" NOT NULL ENABLE,  

    "NAME" VARCHAR2(80 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,  

    "GROUP_ID" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE,  

    "ENTRY_PRICE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0,  

    "RETAIL_PRICE" NUMBER DEFAULT 0,  

    "COUNT" NUMBER(*,0) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE,  

     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("ID") 

  USING INDEX PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255 COMPUTE STATISTICS  

  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 

  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 

  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 

  TABLESPACE "USERS"  ENABLE,  

     CONSTRAINT "PRODUCT_FK1" FOREIGN KEY ("GROUP_ID") 

      REFERENCES "USER1"."PRODUCT_GROUP" ("ID") ENABLE 

   ) SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE  

  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255  

 NOCOMPRESS LOGGING 

  STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1 MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 

  PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1 

  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) 

  TABLESPACE "USERS" ; 

 

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE"  

BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON product 

FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

  DECLARE 

    v_markup product_group.markup%TYPE; 

    -- Получаем наценку на группу товара 

  BEGIN 

    SELECT markup 

    INTO v_markup 

    FROM product_group 

    WHERE id = :NEW.group_id; 

 

    -- Вычисляем розничную цену 

    :NEW.retail_price := :NEW.entry_price * (1 + v_markup); 

  EXCEPTION 

    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN 

      -- Eсли группа товара не найдена 

      :NEW.retail_price := NULL; 

  END; 

   -- Выполняем коммит изменений 

  COMMIT; 

EXCEPTION 

  WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    NULL; 

END; 

/ 

ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_RETAIL_PRICE" ENABLE; 

 

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT"  

AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON product 

FOR EACH ROW 

DECLARE 

  v_group_id NUMBER; 

BEGIN 

  -- Получаем идентификатор группы товаров для текущего товара 

  SELECT group_id INTO v_group_id 

  FROM product 

  WHERE id = :NEW.id; 

 

  -- Обновляем количество товаров в группе 

  UPDATE product_group 

  SET count = ( 

    SELECT count 

    FROM product 

    WHERE group_id = v_group_id 

  ); 

 

  -- Обновляем сводную стоимость группы 

  UPDATE product_group 

  SET c_retail = ( 

    SELECT (entry_price * count) 

    FROM product 

    WHERE group_id = v_group_id 

  ); 

 

  -- Выполняем коммит изменений 

  COMMIT; 

EXCEPTION 

  WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    NULL; 

END ; 

/ 

ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_GROUP_COUNT" ENABLE; 

 

  CREATE OR REPLACE NONEDITIONABLE TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_C_RETAIL_TRIGGER"  

AFTER UPDATE ON product FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN 

  -- Пересчитываем сводную стоимость для соответствующей группы 

  UPDATE product_group pg 

  SET c_retail = ( 

    SELECT (p.retail_price * p.count) 

    FROM product p 

    WHERE p.group_id = pg.id 

  ) 

  WHERE id = :NEW.group_id; 

   -- Выполняем коммит изменений 

  COMMIT; 

EXCEPTION 

  WHEN OTHERS THEN 

    NULL; 

END; 

/ 

ALTER TRIGGER "USER1"."UPDATE_C_RETAIL_TRIGGER" ENABLE;
```

Comment: Вы не должны обращаться из триггера на строку к той же самой таблице на которую сделан триггер. Этого легко добиться, если не считать sum() по целой группе записей. Достаточно вычислить разницу между NEW.count и OLD.count (не забываем что они могут быть null) и добавить эту разницу к значению в таблице product_group

Comment: спасибо за совет,помогло

Answer (score 0):

Вы внутри триггера `BEFORE INSERT`, в таблице этого значения ещё нет, не с чего считать количество.
Подсчёт количества нужно перенести в `AFTER INSERT` триггер.

Comment: У меня возникает ошибка, если переделать на after. Указал ее в вопросе